# Creating XML file using StreamingMarkupBuilder() in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

i have a groovy method that now creates XML files. I have verified it using the groovyConsole. But if i use this snippet in my jenkinsfile, the XML file is not seen to be created in the workspace, although the job completes successfully.

Question: how do i make sure that the XML file is generated in the workspace? I will be using this XML for subsequent stages in the jenkinsfile

Here is how the jenkinsfile looks like:

```
import groovy.xml.*

node('master') {

  deleteDir()

  stage('Checkout') {
   // checks out the code
  }

 generateXML("deploy.xml")  //This calls the method to generate the XML file


  //stage for packaging



  //Stage to Publish


  //Stage to Deploy


}


  @NonCPS
  def generateXML(file1) {

    println "Generating the manifest XML........"

    def workflows = [
    [ name: 'A', file: 'fileA', objectName: 'wf_A', objectType: 'workflow', sourceRepository: 'DEV2', folderNames: [ multifolder: '{{multifolderTST}}', multifolder2: '{{multifolderTST2}}' ]],

    [ name: 'B', file: 'fileB', objectName: 'wf_B', objectType: 'workflow', sourceRepository: 'DEV2', folderNames: [ multifolder3: '{{multifolderTST3}}', multifolder4: '{{multifolderTST4}}']]
    ]

     def builder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
    builder.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    new File(file1).newWriter() << builder.bind {
      mkp.xmlDeclaration()
      mkp.declareNamespace(udm :'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')
      mkp.declareNamespace(powercenter:'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')
      delegate.udm.DeploymentPackage(version:'$BUILD_NUMBER', application: "informaticaApp"){
        delegate.deployables {
          workflows.each { item ->
            delegate.powercenter.PowercenterXml(name:item.name, file:item.file) {
              delegate.scanPlaceholders(true)
              delegate.sourceRepository(item.sourceRepository)
              delegate.folderNameMap {
                item.folderNames.each { name, value ->
                  it.entry(key:name, value)
                }
              }
              delegate.objectNames {
                delegate.value(item.objectName)
              }
              delegate.objectTypes {
                delegate.value(item.objectType)
              }
            }
          }
        }
        delegate.dependencyResolution('LATEST')
        delegate.undeployDependencies(false)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're showing the code, and you say the "file is not seen to be created in the workspace", but how have you determined this?  Are you running other code that checks for it, or are you physically browsing the workspace directory tree, or what?

Comment: i am going in and checking for the XML in the workspace

Comment: Okay - just dug'ed up more.. and the file was under / (root dir) ... hmm, i was hoping that the file will be generated w.r.t. jenkins workspace. !!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the file in the / dir.. As i haven't entered any path in the filewriter.

UPDATE: 
this is not the right solution for a distributed env. It appears that the java file io operations only works in master and not in the agent machines.